# Creating Help Files - Applescript Studio

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-studio, help-files

I would like to know how to generate help files for an applescript studio application I am currently creating.  I have tried many different options of creating help, and googled it for quite some time and cannot find an answer.

When I click on the menu item "Application Help" in my application it opens Help Viewer with an empty window when I attempt to create the help.

I am currently running Tiger with Xcode 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately these ways haven't worked for me, but thank you for the replies.  I have switched my programming languages and don't use applescript studio anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [HelpLogic by Electric Butterfly](http://www.ebutterfly.com/helplogic/) for several projects and have never had a problem.

Comment: Hmm...  Nice interface but doesn't seem to work.  I might not be using it right...  I indexed the help created by the application with Help Indexer it produced a few errors and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

- [Mac Help Writer](http://www.artistictechworks.com/machelpwriter.html)
- [Simple Help Editor](http://www.pandaware.com/simple/index.html)
- [QuickHelp](http://www.excelsoftware.com/newsquickhelp_400.html)

The applications listed first are the more recently updated.
I personally use [Mac Help Writer](http://www.artistictechworks.com/machelpwriter.html), and I find it helpful.